# Unicode to PHP exec

Tags: php, python, unicode, exec

I have a Python file I'm calling with PHP's `exec` function. Python then outputs a string (apparently Unicode, based on using `isinstance`), which is echoed by PHP. The problem I'm running into is that if my string has any special characters in it (like the degree symbol), it won't output. I'm sure I need to do something to fiddle with the encoding, but I'm not really sure what to do, and why.

**EDIT:** To get an idea of how I am calling `exec`, please see the following code snippet:

```
$tables = shell_exec('/s/python-2.6.2/bin/python2.6 getWikitables.py '.$title);
```

Python properly outputs the string when I call `getWikitables.py` by itself.

**EDIT:** It definitely seems to be something either on the Python end, or in transmitting the results. When I run `strlen` on the returned values in PHP, I get 0. Can `exec` only accept a certain type of encoding?

Comment: Can you post a code snippet illustrating how you are calling exec to get the string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On php you can use methods like [`utf8_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.utf8-encode.php) or [`utf8_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.utf8-decode.php) to solve your problem.

Comment: Neither worked - is it possible the problem is in transmitting from Python to php and I need to do something on the Python side?

Comment: Maybe, or can be the php output charset. Try it `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and tell me if you get a different result.

Comment: You need take a look on Multibyte library of PHP. This can tell you what is the returned encoding, and you can turn it to utf-8 and make _visible_.

Answer (score 12):

Try setting the `LANG` environment variable immediately before executing the Python script per http://php.net/shell-exec#85095:

```
shell_exec(sprintf(
  'LANG=en_US.utf-8; /s/python-2.6.2/bin/python2.6 getWikitables.py %s',
    escapeshellarg($title)
));
```

(use of [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) to (hopefully) make it a little easier to follow the lengthy string)

You might also/instead need to do this before calling `shell_exec()`, per http://php.net/shell-exec#78279:

```
$locale = 'en_US.utf-8';
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
```

Comment: Oh god, I just spent 6 hours on this ! The second solution fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar issue and solved it with the following. I don't understand why it is necessary, since I though all is already processed with UTF-8. Calling my Python script on the command line worked, but not with exec (shell_exec) via PHP and Apache.

According to a [php forum entry](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php#99213) this one is needed when you want to use [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php):

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
```

It needs to be called before `escapeshellarg()` is executed. Also, it was necessary to set a certain [Python environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) before the exec command (found an unrelated hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44938230/57091)):

```
putenv("PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8");
```

My Python script evaluated the arguments like this:

```
sys.argv[1].decode("utf-8")
```

(Hint: That was required because I use a [library](https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper) to convert some arabic texts.)

So finally, I could imagine that the original question could be solved this way:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
putenv("PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8");
$tables = shell_exec('/s/python-2.6.2/bin/python2.6 getWikitables.py ' .
          escapeshellarg($title));
```

But I cannot tell anything regarding the return value. In my case I could output it to the browser directly without any problems.

Spent many, many hours to find that out... One of the situations when I hate my job ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
putenv("PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8");
$tables = shell_exec('/s/python-2.6.2/bin/python2.6 getWikitables.py ' .
      escapeshellarg($title));
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.