# Output from shell_exec() containing accented charcters getting mangled

Tags: php, shell, encoding, character-encoding

I've got a command which I'm running from PHP using [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/shell_exec).
Sometimes the output of the command will contain accented characters.

When run from Bash, the output appears correctly.  However, when run from `shell_exec`, the accented characters are lost and the output truncated somewhat.

Example output from `Bash`:

```
.                                   D        0  Tue Oct 25 16:45:26 2011
..                                  D        0  Tue Oct 25 16:45:26 2011

...

Background pres for political speech maggie & gemma.ppt      A  3323392  Fri Oct 24   14:31:26 2008
extra listening exercise on la télévision.doc      A    24064  Wed Jan 11 08:12:32 2006
gender of nouns.ppt                 A    42496  Fri Sep 10 07:55:42 2004

...

            63999 blocks of size 8388608. 36710 blocks available
```

Example output from `shell_exec` - note what happens to `télévision`, `vidéo` etc.:

```
.                                   D        0  Tue Oct 25 16:45:26 2011
..                                  D        0  Tue Oct 25 16:45:26 2011

...

Background pres for political speech maggie & gemma.ppt      A  3323392  Fri Oct 24 14:31:26 2008
extra listening exercise on la t  gender of nouns.ppt                 A    42496  Fri Sep 10 07:55:42 2004

...

    63999 blocks of size 8388608. 36710 blocks available
```

Comment: The *bash* is using some other encoding than `shell_exec`. Try to find out which shell `shell_exec` is making use of and compare the encoding configuration between the two. Add both to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unicode to PHP exec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065557/unicode-to-php-exec) - especially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6066720/367456).

Comment: hakre, you're correct. I'd seen that answer but not spotted that it proposed 2 different solutions, I'd only tried the first.  Trying the second one solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer below and accept it. There are not many questions like yours so I think it's worth to have it solved here, too. You can accept your answer later on (yes, that works). This will help to make this site working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to run these commands before shell_exec, to make sure that the correct locale was being used:

```
$locale = 'en_GB.utf-8';
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
```

Presumably you can just change en_GB to whatever your language is. I noticed that the locale string seems to be case sensitive.