# Getting ?? characters when calling a jar file through php code

Tags: java, php, jar, character-encoding

I'm developing a service in PHP that calls a jar file with the exec function, this way:

```
$text = "string with accents á, ó, ú or العربية";

exec("java -jar jarfile.jar '$text'", $data);
```

When I test the jar file with the command `java -jar jarfile.jar "string with accents á, ó, ú or العربية"` in a linux console it works well and jar file, through System.out.println, returns the text well encoded, but when executed by PHP I recive **??** where should be accented characters or arabic text.

I've tried `mb_detect_encoding($data);` and it says its encoding is ASCII, so I've executed `$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'utf8', 'ASCII');` but still recieving the **??** characters.

Any help in what I should do to get characters with the right encoding?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following 2 environment works for me. You can also try it:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LOCALE=UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help in my case.

Comment: I must correct @Ambrish, your answer was right. With a wiser colleague and this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9398210/271804 we've solved. Thank you!