# PHP exec() works in command line but not in web

Tags: php, exec, raspbian

I'm trying to use jarun's "[googler](https://github.com/jarun/googler)" in a PHP script in order to search YouTube and find the URL of the first result. The command I'm executing is `googler --np --json -C -n 1 -w youtube.com -x <name of youtube video>`, and it works perfectly on my local machine. Here is my code:

```
<?php
exec("googler --np --json -C -n 1 -w youtube.com -x thomas the dank engine", $results);
var_dump($results);
?>
```

When I execute this in the command line, it works perfectly as it should, but when I do it via a web browser or a GET request, it does not work. I am aware that it is being executed as another user. In my case, it's the user `www-data`, so I gave that user full sudo permissions without a password, and did the following commands:

```
sudo -u pi googler --np --json -C -n 1 -w youtube.com -x thomas the dank engine
```

as well as

```
su - pi -c 'googler --np --json -C -n 1 -w youtube.com -x thomas the dank engine'
```

neither of these worked. Does it have to do with googler? What am I doing wrong?

When adding `2>&1` to the command, I get the following error message:

> stdout encoding 'ascii' detected. googler requires utf-8 to work properly. The wrong encoding may be due to a non-UTF-8 locale or an improper PYTHONIOENCODING. (For the record, your locale language is and locale encoding is ; your PYTHONIOENCODING is not set.) Please set a UTF-8 locale (e.g., en_US.UTF-8) or set PYTHONIOENCODING to utf-8.

Comment: Maybe `googler` isn't in its `$PATH`, try using the full pathname.

Comment: Capture the error output with `2>&1` at the end of the command being sent to `exec()`.

Comment: What's the actual error that PHP gives you?

Comment: "so I gave that user full sudo permissions without a password" - this is never the way to go about things!

Comment: Sounds like you need to set some environment variables in the PHP script, similar to what you probably do in your `.profile`.

Comment: @Barmar I don't need to since it's in the directory that it's being executed from... I'm simply doing `./googler <params>`. Is it an issue with the Python script?

Comment: Environment variables are set in `~/.profile` and `/etc/profile` when you login. The webserver doesn't login interactively, so it doesn't execute a profile script. The `googler` script is apparently dependent on the locale setting, and those variables aren't set. Try putting `putenv("LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8");` in the PHP script before calling `exec()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting:

```
putenv("PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8");
```

in the script before calling `exec()`. `googler` apparently requires the locale or this environment variable to be set.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove `exec` from the `disable_functions` parameter in the php.ini file for your server module installation of PHP (which is separate from your CLI installation). It is typically disabled by default for the server module.

Comment: I've been able to do `exec("whoami")` successfully, so this is not the issue.

Comment: I apologize for the incorrect answer. I gave my best guess based on the information provided.