# Python3 - 'utf-16-le' codec can't encode character '\udce2' in position 12: surrogates not allowed

Tags: python, php, python-3.x

I recently changed servers that my python script was running on and I now get the this error:

> 'utf-16-le' codec can't encode character '\udce2' in position 12:
> surrogates not allowed

Script was running fine on previous server. The script takes commandline arguments and uses mutagen for mp3 tag processing. Here's part of the script itself:

```
    if args.title:
        audio.add(TIT2(encoding=3, text=u"" + args.title))
    if args.artist:
        audio.add(TPE1(encoding=3, text=u"" + args.artist))
    if args.album:
        audio.add(TALB(encoding=3, text=u"" + args.album))
    if args.year:
        audio.add(TYER(encoding=3, text=u"" + args.year))
    if args.track:
        audio.add(TRCK(encoding=3, text=u"" + args.track))
    if args.genre:
        audio.add(TCON(encoding=3, text=u"" + args.genre))
    if args.comment:
        audio.add(COMM(encoding=3, lang='eng', desc=u'', text=u"" + args.comment))
    if args.TXXX:
        # We used append when created TXXX argument, so we have an array of all TXXX tags
        # Tag is given in the form of --TXXX "SCRIPTURETEXT:Job 1:1" so we will iterate through them
        # and split on first colon. This should give tag's custom name (desc) in first element of array and
        # tag contents (text) in the second element
        for x in args.TXXX:
            tmptag = x.split(':', maxsplit=1)
            audio.add(TXXX(encoding=3, desc=u"" + tmptag[0], text=u"" + tmptag[1]))
    if args.picture:
        # Embed cover-art in ID3 metadata
        img_path = "/var/www/apps/audiodb/_resources/images/speakers/" + args.picture
        if path.isfile(img_path): # check if file exists
            audio.add(APIC(encoding=3, mime='image/jpg', type=3,
                          desc=u'Cover', data=open(img_path, 'rb').read()))

    audio.save(filename,v2_version=3)
    print ("MP3 tags successfully written.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer to the problem. My python script was called via PHP using the `exec` command. When the python script parsed the commandline arguments, one of the fields contained the character – which caused the UTF error message. So, in my php script, I added these lines before I called the `exec` command.

```
$locale = 'en_US.utf-8';
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
```

Thanks, to the [Unicode to PHP exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065557/unicode-to-php-exec) post for helping figure out my issue.